# Tex file just showing what looks like binary code after restarting computer

Tags: texstudio

My computer crashed so I restarted it. When I opened the tex file I was working on (in TexStudio) it just shows code which looks like its in binary or something. I can't copy and past on stack exchange, so heres a screenshot of the first few lines:

[image: Snippet of Code]

Comment: RIFF WAVE format is a microsoft wav format sound file,...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, interesting, I don't know whats happened then or how that's replaced the tex file

Comment: you could try renaming the file to .wav and see if it plays

Comment: Yeah you're right, it does play. I wonder why my tex file has changed to some random .wav file. I have a backup for my work, so will work on that for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is a Microsoft `.wav` format sound file. How it came to over-write your tex source I can not guess.